# Forcing a Program (FFmpeg) to Fork in BASH

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ffmpeg

I'm trying to fork an instance of FFmpeg so it will run in the background in a way that I could include in a script, but the obvious way doesn't seem to work with it:

```
 ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -f concat -i list.txt -c copy -f flv -flvflags no_duration_filesize -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -preset veryfast rtmp://[streaming_server_info] &
```

While the ampersand usually sends a process on its merry way, in this case ffmpeg never starts streaming if I initiate it that way. It shows the basic ffmpeg start up information without any sorts of errors and then is killed when I try to press return to use the tty for anything else.

Here's how it starts:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro ' --extra-cflags=' ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-fontconfig --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-libdrm --enable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nvenc --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --disable-encoder=libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-libmodplug --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-libmfx --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
```

I *have* managed to get ffmpeg to cooperate, but only by starting it without the ampersand, letting it start streaming, stopping it using Ctrl+Z and then starting it back up with `bg`. After that, it runs just fine in the background.

That process is fine, but I'd like to do the equivalent in a way that could be put in a bash script. Is there a way to get the equivalent of Ctrl+Z plus `bg` accomplished in a way that is scriptable like using an ampersand would be?

*Side note:* Please remove this side note if it improper to mention this, but if anyone with FFmpeg knowledge happens to read this question, which I'm putting on SuperUser since it is the actual question isn't to do with FFmpeg but a bash/forking issue, I'd be grateful if the said person would also take a gander at a question I posted a week or so ago specifically on a problem with the FFmpeg parameters I used above over on the less busy [Video Production StackExchange](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/32842/infinite-loop-rtmp-stream-using-ffmpeg-or-equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-d` global option for daemon mode:

```
ffmpeg -d -stream_loop -1 -re -f concat -i list.txt -c copy -f flv -flvflags no_duration_filesize -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -preset veryfast rtmp://[streaming_server_info]
```